# SendGrid, which properties to use to merge URL and tittle (text) into clickable text (hyperlink)?

Tags: email, sendgrid

I have data in .CSV file namely: {url} and {title}. What type of properties/tokens I can apply in email template (using Module: text) to get {title + url} as clickable text (hyperlink).

I don't have coding skills so please use explanation as simple as possible if any type of code is required.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the Design Editor, right?
In this case you need to add `{{text}}` (or in your case `title`) within the text module and hit the "Link button" in the left-hand sidebar.

[image: showing the side bar]

A dialog should pop up in which you can enter the placeholder for the `{{url}}`

[image]